# Why is git not pushing contents of a folder?

Tags: django, git, heroku

After copying a folder 'myapp' into to my working folder, I do the following to add it to my staging area:

```
git add .
```

and then commit the changes:

```
git commit
```

Then I push my changes to Heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```

So my folder, called 'myapp' is present on heroku, but the problem is that it's completely empty.

When I do the following,

```
git clone myapp myapp2
```

the folder clones properly on my local machine with all expected subcontents.

Does anyone know why the subfolders' contents are not being pushed to Heroku properly? What am I doing wrong?

To answer the questions below:

1. I am doing the `git add .` in my top level folder (the folder that contains folder `myapp`). Doing `git status` shows `no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
2. Yes, `myapp` contains files/folders (my django project)
3. I deleted my .gitignore file because I placed my virtual environment in another place altogeher so it's no longer in my project folder so I don't think that's affecting it.

Comment: Are you doing `git add .` in the `myapp` folder or somewhere else? What does `git status` show after you committed?

Comment: Are there any files in the folder myapp? Because git does not track directories, only files inside the directories.

Comment: Are the files being excluded by .gitignore?

Comment: I updated the question with answers to these questions. The strange thing is that git status shows `no changes to commit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I seemed to have solved the problem.  Somehow git got in a weird state. I don't really understand how, but for some reason it wasn't adding any of the files in the folder.

I simply copied that folder and gave it a new name, and then followed the exact same process I had been doing all along, and it finally uploaded properly.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you cannot push changes to a checked-out branch of a repository.  It usually causes major problems!  Here is what usually happens:

```
$ git push heroku master
...error messages...
To heroku
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'heroku'
```

Since you haven't mentioned any *error messages*, I'm assuming that you've added the following to your `heroku` repository configuration, or you're running a fairly old version of Git:

```
[receive]
        denyCurrentBranch = false
```

It sounds like you want to check out a fresh copy of the master branch whenever you push a new version to your `heroku` repository.  That can be achieved with a post-receive hook.  Create a file in your `heroku` repository `.git/hooks/post-receive`, and give it `+x` permissions.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    if test "$refname" = refs/heads/master
    then
        ( cd ..; GIT_DIR=.git; git reset --hard )
    fi
done
```

Now, whenever you push a new `master` branch to `heroku`, the hook will run and check out the new branch.  There are better ways to do this kind of thing, but this is simple.

**Summary:** By default, when you push changes, it only changes the *history* but not the *working tree*.  The assumption is that someone might be working on that tree, so doing anything to it could be destructive.

Comment: I don't receive any error messages, and the strange thing is if I create a new subfolder called `TestFolder` and create a text file in it called `TestFile.txt` then that is indeed pushed to heroku. Yet the `myapp` folder remains empty where I have my Django app stored.

Comment: 1) Try doing `git ls-tree -r --name-only master` on the client.  If this does not show all your files, then you have not committed them yet.  2) If that shows all of your files, try doing `git reset --hard master` on the server to check them out.  3) If that doesn't work, run `git rev-parse master` on both client and server, and see if they match.

Comment: 1) This command shows all files 2) When I run that command on the server I get `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. But `git status` shows I'm on branch master. When I do `git reset --hard` I get `fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref`.

Comment: If HEAD is not a valid ref, then it looks like you don't have anything checked out yet.  Try `git checkout master` on the server, or try checking out something on the server side.

Comment: Ok I'm no longer getting that error message. I think I had done something odd to get that. But I still haven't made progress on this problem. I just still don't understand how I could create a separate folder with a text file and have that commit properly but then this Django app folder is completely empty. I followed the same process in both cases. I'm not that familiar with git, but logic tells me that if I follow the same process and get different results, maybe there's something wrong with the contents of the folder not being recognized?

Comment: The problem here is that when you say "this Django app folder is completely empty", 1) I don't know which repository and 2) I don't know what's supposed to be in the folder, if anything and 3) I don't know which steps you've taken in the meantime, such as commits, pushes, and checkouts.  It sounds like you need someone on IRC to walk you through the process step by step.